# Can't open any doors on Floor 63

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I'm playing FF7 in emulator with [this walkthrough](http://jegged.com/Games/Final-Fantasy-VII/Walkthrough/Disc-1/06-Shinra-Building.html) and on Floor 63, I can't get any doors open. Any idea why is that? Is it a bug or did I miss somethings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Check the computer first

In the room just south of the stairwell is a large computer console with various lights flashing on it. In order to open any of the large hallway doors on this floor, you first need to check that computer, which will tell you that your security clearance allows you to open 3 doors. This is the same computer that allows you to reset your opened doors and trade in your prize coupons. After that, simply follow the walkthrough you already have.